# Converting datetime to unix timestamp in mySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp, insert-into

So here's the thing, I have the database 'example' with two tables:

'exampletable1' contains two columns 'ID','datetime'

'exampletable2' contains two columns 'id2','timestamp'

(both ID fields are primary keys and auto incremented)

I'm trying to import elements (rows) from exampletable1 to exampletable2, but when it's giving me NULL in the 'timestamp' field. so I tried to use the FORMAT(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP you talked about, but it's not working, neither the code you posted.

Here's the queries I'm executing:

```
INSERT INTO `exampletable2`(`timestamp`)
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) FROM `exampletable1`
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO `exampletable2`(`timestamp`)
SELECT FORMAT(`datetime`,TIMESTAMP) FROM `exampletable1`
```

I appreciate any help guys!

Comment: What's datatype of `datetime` and `timestamp`

Comment: the same as their names: 'datetime' is 'datetime', and 'timestamp' is 'unix_timestamp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reformat/convert anything. Just do

```
INSERT INTO exampletable2 (timestamp)
SELECT datetime 
  FROM exampletable1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63831/1)** demo

Recommended reading

- [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I did try it, and it returned a NULL value!

Comment: Did you take a look at working sqlfiddle example? Can you edit the provided sqlfiddle, click 'Build Schema' and post the link here?

Comment: Well, the SQLFiddle shows it's totally working, maybe it has to do with the version, I'm using phpMyAdmin, I'll try to update its version

Comment: I updated the phpMyAdmin, I don't know what's the problem, but it's still returning zero values for the date.
However, thank you very much for you help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert `DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP`, just insert them directly:

```
INSERT INTO `exampletable2`(`timestamp`)
SELECT `datetime` FROM `exampletable1`
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13b19/2)

You can check more about this type here: [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I did try it, and it returned a NULL value!

Comment: I'm sorry it's a ZERO not NULL.